# How to open specific page on Flutter firebase push Notification in all state?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The Notification is working great, while it is in the terminated state,

just there is a problem, If I receive 2 notifications with indexes 2 and 3 respectively, then when I open the first notification with index 2 then it opens the second page which is okay, but when I minimize the app and click on notification with index 3 then it also shows the page of index 2, not index 3.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Handling a background message ${message.notification!.title!}');
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'High Importance Notifications',
  importance: Importance.high,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Initialize Firebase Messaging for background handling
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // Initialize Flutter Local Notifications
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  // Set foreground notification presentation options
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  // Retrieve Firebase Cloud Messaging token
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("token is $token");
    }
  });

  // Initialize GetStorage for local storage
  await GetStorage.init();

  // Apply custom HTTP overrides if needed
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

  // Start the app
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureFirebaseMessagingAndLocalNotifications();

    // Subscribe to the 'all' topic for Firebase Cloud Messaging
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
  }

  void _configureFirebaseMessagingAndLocalNotifications() async {
    // Request permission to receive notifications
    NotificationSettings settings =
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    }

    // Configure Firebase messaging background handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if(initialMessage != null){
      _openFunActivityWithIndex(initialMessage);
    }

    // Configure Firebase messaging handler when the app is in the foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      final pageIndex = int.tryParse(message.data['news_id'] ?? '');
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Received message: ${message.notification!.title!}');
        print('Received pageIndex: ${pageIndex.toString()}');
      }
      _displayNotification(message.notification!);
    });

    // Configure Firebase messaging handler when the app is terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Message opened from the terminated state: ${message.notification!.title}');
      }
      _openFunActivityWithIndex(message);
    });

    // Initialize the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_nu');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  Future<void> _displayNotification(RemoteNotification notification) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      importance: Importance.high,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_nu',
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      channel.name, // Notification title - This is now included in the styleInformation
      null, // Notification message
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
    _showNotification(notification.title!);
  }

  void _showNotification(String title,) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      importance: Importance.high,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_nu',
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
      fullScreenIntent: true,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      title, // Notification title
      null, // Notification message
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
  }

  void _openFunActivityWithIndex(RemoteMessage message) {
    final pageIndex = int.tryParse(message.data['news_id'] ?? '');
    if (pageIndex != null) {
      Get.to(() => FunActivity(index: pageIndex));
    } else {
      // Handle the case where the index is null or not provided in the notification
      Get.to(() => FunActivity(index: 0)); // Default to the first index or adjust as needed
    }
  }
```